# Creating the production for a CFG

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have to create the productions for a CFG that follows

$$\{a^ib^jc^k : j = i + k\}$$

I can get close to the answer. I found

$$\begin{align*}
&A\to aAb \mid B\\
&B\to bBc \mid \epsilon
\end{align*}$$

but that allows c's in the wrong place. I need help creating the productions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the language L may be rewritten as $\{ a^ib^îb^kc^k \}$ - now it should be easier to come up with a grammar:

$ S \to AB \\ 
  A \to aAb \,|\, \epsilon \\ 
  B \to bBc \,|\, \epsilon $

Comment: Thanks! I thought I needed a variable on the end, but I couldn't figure out how to get it without having a bunch of them interspersed in the string.